# Is there any way to fork the SBT console into a new JVM?

Tags: scala, sbt

For all the reasons listed here:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Running-Project-Code.html

it's sometimes necessary to run your Scala code in a separate JVM from the one in which SBT is running. That's also true of the REPL, which you access from the console or test:console commands.

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that SBT supports running the console in its own JVM (and I'm posting this question here, as requested in the message):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/W0q62PfSIMo

Can someone confirm that this isn't possible and suggest a possible workaround? I'm trying to play with a ScalaFX app in the console, and I have to quit SBT completely each time I run it. It'd be nice to just have to quit the console and keep SBT running.

Comment: Here is a link to watch the open issue for others: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1918. Looks like you already commented on it!

Comment: That issue suggests it's related to https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/975 which is a problem with fork, generally, but based on the discussion in the group, it doesn't look like this should currently work, even if the other issue were fixed. I should have provided a link for that, however. Thanks for adding it.